# Displaying Data into html table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am a neophyte programmer in php and I am always seeking for the solution of this problem. If anyone has an idea pls. post your answer and I am thankful for your great ideas to solve this stuff.

In my database table I have data like this:

[image: tblattendance]

In my php page I want to present in this way using html table.
[image: Html Table as output]

Could anyone help me doing this stuff? Thank you very much…

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$SQL = "select NAME, WEEK, STATUS from tblattendance order by NAME, SUBSTRING(WEEK,1,LENGTH(WEEK) - 2) ASC";

$data = $db->query($SQL);

$last_name = "";
echo '<table><tr><th>NAME</th><th>1st WEEK</th><th>2nd WEEK</th><th>3rd WEEK</th><th>4th WEEK</th>';
while($row = $data->fetch_assoc()){
    if($last_name != $row["NAME"]){
        $last_name = $row["NAME"];
        echo '</tr>';
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$row["NAME"].'</td>';
    }
    echo '<td>'.$row["STATUS"].'</td>';
}
echo '</tr></table>';
```

Comment: Please note that `ORDER BY week ASC` will sort `2th`, `3th` and `30th` as `2th`, `30th`, `3th`, because they are ordered as strings.

Comment: Aw, I hadn't noticed they were strings. Thought they were numbers. Check my update.

Comment: If you start `SUBSTRING` at the 0th character, it will return nothing (has to be `1`). It still has the same problem, because it still compares two strings with each other. To combat the problem, use `LPAD( WEEK, 10, "0" )` instead. `0003th` is less than `0030th`, because the character `3` has a higher character value than `0` and it compares strings of equal length, where `3th` and `30th` are sorted the other way around because `t` has a higher value than `0` (and `4` in `4` is 'more' than `3` in `30`).

Comment: You are correct about the 0, I will change that. However I think the way you are doing the comparison is very long winded - why not do the substring, then cast to an integer?

Comment: Because it is how I would do that. That doesn't mean it is the best solution, or the only solution. It just means it works ^_^. OP should have used integers in the first place I think.

Comment: Thank you so much friends for all your brilliant ideas..i'm so much surprised that u quickly responded my post...GOD BLESS YOU ALWAYS friends.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are searching for the functionality of `GROUP_CONCAT` in mysql ([docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)). You would get something like:

```sql
SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT( week ), GROUP_CONCAT( there )
FROM presence
GROUP BY name;
```

which will return the following results you can parse using `explode()` in php ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)):

```
Andrew  4th,1st,3rd,2nd     Present,Present,Present,Present
John    1st,4th,3rd,2nd     Absent,Present,Present,Present
Mark    2nd,3rd,1st,4th     Present,Present,Present,Present
Micheal 2nd,3rd,4th,1st     Absent,Absent,Absent,Present
```

On a side note: If you haven't settled on a database scheme yet, it might be better to use an int for the week number column, as it is more reliable when sorting and easier to manipulate.

Sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc785/1

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
$sql="select distinct name from tblattendance;";
$res=$mysqli->query($sql);
if($res){
   while($row=$res->fetch_assoc()){
       $name=$row['name'];
       $sql="select week, status from tblattendance where name='$name';";
       $res1=$mysqli->query($sql);
   }
}
```